# django static file - 404

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

First of all: I know there are a lot of user issues but all of them did not solve my issue, so im hoping for the best here. My django is unable to access the static files and im getting the 404.

Infrastructure: Public accesible server with django installed and apache reverse proxy to localhost:8000. (Its no apache Problem. When Local Forwarding of the 8000 Port this issue is still present).

Directory Listing:

```
/var/twirps
.
|-- assets
|   |-- admin
|   |   |-- css
|   |   |   `-- vendor
|   |   |       `-- select2
|   |   |-- fonts
|   |   |-- img
|   |   |   `-- gis
|   |   `-- js
|   |       |-- admin
|   |       `-- vendor
|   |           |-- jquery
|   |           |-- select2
|   |           |   `-- i18n
|   |           `-- xregexp
|   |-- css
|   |   `-- images
|   |-- js
|   |-- sass
|   |   `-- libs
|   `-- webfonts
|-- blockmatrix
|   |-- __pycache__
|   `-- migrations
|-- static
|   |-- css
|   |   `-- images
|   |-- js
|   |-- sass
|   |   `-- libs
|   `-- webfonts
|-- templates
`-- twirps
    `-- __pycache__
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
        ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

My static files declaration index.html (In templates folder):

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'static/css/main.css' %}" />
```

And i also already did `python3 manage.py collectstatic`

Still the static files wont get loaded and im seeing the 404 error in the django server log. Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your Apache config for how you are serving the static files. There is some configuration you do in production in order to serve the static files from Apache, and you didn't mention in your question if you did that or not. You should **not** be serving the static files directly from Django unless you are in development mode (i.e. `DEBUG=True`), which you shouldn't be.

From the documentation:

> Serving the site and your static files from the same server If you
> want to serve your static files from the same server that’s already
> serving your site, the process may look something like:
>
> (1) Push your code up to the deployment server.
>
> (2) On the server, run collectstatic to copy all the static files into STATIC_ROOT.
>
> (3) Configure your web server to serve the files in STATIC_ROOT under the URL STATIC_URL.

Documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: But it doesnt even work without Apache as i Said... I do not serve my static Files via apache right now. How am indoing that and why doesnt it work without apache then?

Comment: Are you in development without a server in front of it? I’m not clear on what you’re saying.

Comment: I have a server in front of it. But if i local forward port 8000 that i can access django directly its still not working.

Comment: Are you using WSGI or ASGI on the server or running the Django app in development mode? It is not intended to be run in development mode behind a server.